# Dart: efficiently rebuilding tree structures

Tags: tree, dart

I have an architectural problem. I'm building a computer algebra system in Dart (though the language is largely irrelevant) and want immutable expression trees. [BuiltValue](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/built_value) seems like the perfect base to start from, but I'm pondering the best way of structuring the builder.

Use case: given an expression tree and some manipulation, construct the manipulated expression tree efficiently. Examples:

```
// 2 + 3 -> 5
Sum([Int(2), Int(3)]).simplify() == Int(5)

// (x + y)^2 -> x^2 + 2*x*y + y^2
Power(Sum([Symbol('x'), Symbol('y')]), Int(2)).expand() == Sum(...)
```

Most manipulations will be the result of multiple chained manipulations, and the more I can avoid rebuilding the expressions at each step the better. Sometimes this won't be possible - e.g. after duplications.

Naively I could create a separate builder for each expression type - `IntBuilder`, `SumBuilder` etc. - but during these manipulations the root type can change.

Things I've considered:

- per-class builders - though I'm unsure how to change root-type changes. Simplifications like `Sum([x]).simplify() == x` (or the first example above) wouldn't be too hard to deal with after rebuild, but I'm not sure how they'd work with examples like the second above.
- a single ExpressionBuilder that tracks operands and some enum-like object identifying the resulting subclass.

Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: What do you mean by "Naively I could create a separate builder for each expression type - IntBuilder, SumBuilder etc. - but during these manipulations the root type can change." ? With immutable data structures, the root always changes (the branches and leaves cannot, or they are immutable). Perhaps you could share code about how this is a problem?

Comment: The data contained in the root changes on rebuild, but normally the type does not - i.e. the signature is `Built -> Built`. e.g. a `BuiltList` after rebuilding can have different elements, but it will remain a `BuiltList`. The simplification "the sum of a single element is the element" would have signature `BuiltSum -> BuiltInt`. Also, I'm assuming all children of compound structures are themselves `BuiltValue`s, so are mutable in the rebuild phase.

Comment: I see. I was thrown off by you wanting immutable expression trees. You don't want to always have immutable expression trees, but rather only want immutable results. And by optimize rebuild, you mean minimize "build()" calls. This seems reasonable, glad you found a solution.

Comment: Thanks for asking the questions - answering it made me recognize my uneccessary constraints :).

Answer (score 2):

I was giving myself uneccessary constraints.

While I originally thought all builder manipulations should mutate the instantiating builder and return nothing, the problem becomes much simpler if one simply requires those manipulations to return a builder. `unarySimplify` (builder equivalent of `Sum([x]) -> x`) below.

```
class SumBuilder implements ExpressionBuilder {
    ListBuilder<ExpressionBuilder> args;
    ExpressionBuilder unarySimplify() => args.length == 1? args[0]: this;
}
```